# Language switch with Language Path embedded and Custom Display Name

Tags: multilingual

Our website require fix path structure in different language version, I know when you want to switch language, just put ?sc_lang=xx behind the path. but my condition is language ia part of path and friendly path

for example:

(en) http://xxx.xxx/en/how_this_works

(de) http://xxx.xxx/de/So_funktioniert

The problem is even I can replace the en to de, but how do I know in German version of current page customer display name(how this works -?->So funktioniert.

Additionally, language selector is in Navi page, it with its controller, but each Page Content has its own Controller, therefore Navi controller won't be able to know other rendering's information(ex:item ID) in other placeholder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to obtain correct version of link address by passing itemID to Action Link, therefore create a pgLinkRedirect() in controller

```
    public ActionResult pgRedirect(string itemid)
    {
        var item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(new ID(itemid));

        UrlOptions op = new UrlOptions();
        op.UseDisplayName = true;
        op.LanguageEmbedding = LanguageEmbedding.Always;
        op.LowercaseUrls = true;

        var url = ComponentHelper.DisplayNameHandler(LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, op), 2);

        return Redirect(url);
    }
```

When you need another version of link, pass language name into GetItem as one of parameter.

```
 var item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(new ID(itemid), LanguageManager.GetLanguage(lg));
```

And then

each link in View using Action Link to pass itemID to controller

```
@Html.ActionLink(@item.MenuItemName, "pgRedirect", new { itemid = @item.itemID })
```

so you can get the link correctly!

Answer (score 1):

To build the URL's you should use the LinkManager.

You can fetch the item in the correct language and pass it to the linkmanager to obtain the correct link like

```
var langItem = currentItem.Database.GetItem(currentItem.ID, language);
var url = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(langItem);
```

Comment: Thanks for replay! It is almost working, the issue I stocked is when the display name with space, I can not get correct Item ..

Comment: @Kun-YaoWang how are you getting the item via displayname?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya I get from current page addrees and do some string replacement.

Comment: @HishaamNamooya int segmentTotal = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Segments.Length - 1;
            var curDisplayName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Segments[segmentTotal].Replace("-", " ").Replace(",-d-,", ".");

Comment: @Kun-YaoWang Can you please share the code you mention above on the question itself and also share how you are fetching the item from Sitecore using the displayname

Comment: @HishaamNamooya OK, I will answer my question, just give a time I need to finish the current page working

Comment: @HishaamNamooya please see the above answer, wish it is helpful for you.